# "dumb as soup" what does it mean and why?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've met this phrase in The Big Bang Theory TV-series, it was a phrase of Sheldon's mother after she forced him to go to apologize to the boss to get his job back:

> Leonard, the Lord never gives us more than we can handle. Thankfully,
>   he blessed me with two other children who are dumb as soup.

From the context, it's clearly that it means very stupid. But why? Word **soup** doesn't associate with any kind of stupidity to me. Also, I haven't found any additional meaning or idioms with this word fitted the situation. Is here some play on word involved? I have found other [discussions in the internet](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dumb-as-soup.1013417/) about this subject but with no real answer.

btw: I can't force myself to hear *sou**p*** in that moment. I always hear something like *sou**m***, though subtitles say that it is definitely *sou**p*** word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People say "dumb as [inanimate object]" to indicate "very dumb" with different many inanimate objects used. Some, like "a rock", are used as a general purpose word denoting "something that's really dumb" and are understood globally, while others, like "soup", may be regional or specifically idiomatic to a certain peer group. Others still will be completely made up — native speakers will generally recognize "dumb as [inanimate object]" as an idiom in itself, so you can plug and chug (replace it) with whatever you want, constructing elaborate surreal scenarios like "he's dumb as a pile of especially coarse sand on the beach that a dog has shat on" that will just be understood as "he's really dumb".

Comment: You might want to clarify "plug and chug", just in case; it's a bit of an unusual idiom.

Comment: @Nathan Hmm… perhaps it's used mostly in math.

Comment: And the object the person is compared to varies in different languages and cultures. My knee-jerk phrase is "dumb as bread". Note that you choose an inanimate object that in one way or other is seen as simple - "dumb as a Mars Rover" or "dumb as a Swiss watch" won't really work.

Comment: I understand that one can say "dumb as X" and put instead of X almost everything and it will keep meaning "very dumb", but they do this TV-series for everyone not for some region where it can be common. Is it possible that directors/script writers just want to uncover some features of the character putting in her mouth these words? For example to emphasize that she is from a region where it is common.

Comment: @bjb568 thank you for "plug and chug" it is going to be very helpful expression to me :)

Comment: @Vitaly It's possible — using particular words can indicate characteristics of the character or place.

Comment: I don't find any instances of "dumb as soup" in the ngram viewer.  "Dumb as a rock" and "dumb as a post" are fairly common.  I suspect that this was a term invented by the show writers for humor, to demonstrate that "dumb as" can really be applied to anything (anything simple, as Stephie points out).

Comment: @Vitaly, the character is from Texas, a region known for colorful language.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that the  phrase is really not used by the general American English speaking population.  True it is understandable and I see that many non-American speaking writers are using it, but it is not that pervasive a phrase that everyone on the street is using it.  Understood perhaps, but many will consider strange unless of course they have been following 'The Big Bang Theory' show.